# Stream MP4 video onto iPhone directly from S3?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I have a bunch of MP4 files on S3.  Is it possible to stream MP4 video content onto iPhone directly from S3?  If so, how can I do this?  If I can't do this, what options do I have for streaming video to iPhone? (e.g. run HLs streaming server on EC2? pseudo-streaming or progressive media download?)

Cloudfront can stream video but apparently only using RTMP protocol which is not supported natively by iOS.  I'd like to stream natively (make things easier).  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream, but the video file must be segmented into .ts files and an .m3u8 file that lists the segments. See https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: 3 years later... is this still the case?

Comment: You know I haven't worked with this technology for a while, so I'm not sure.